# I can't see any signal on the CAN_TX line

Tags: c, stm32, can-bus

I try to use the CAN bus on an STM32F303 discovery board, and I am using the PD0→RX and PD1→TX pins.

I want to try to send a message and analyse on the oscilloscope. So my configuration is seen below in the code blocks.

When I analyse with the oscilloscope which pins are PD0 and PD1, I can't see anything on the oscilloscope.

Where is my fault?

This is my code:

```
#include <stm32f30x.h>
#include <stm32f30x_i2c.h>
#include <stm32f30x_rcc.h>
#include <stm32f30x_syscfg.h>
#include <stm32f30x_exti.h>
// #include <stm32f30x_misc.h>
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"
#include "io_periph_defs.h"
#include "stm32f30x.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "conf.h"

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
CAN_InitTypeDef CAN_InitStructure;
CAN_FilterInitTypeDef CAN_FilterInitStructure;
CAN_InitTypeDef CAN_InitStructure;
CAN_FilterInitTypeDef CAN_FilterInitStructure;
CanTxMsg TxMessage;
CanRxMsg RxMessage;

void Init_TxMes(CanTxMsg *TxMessage)
{
    /* Transmit INITIALIZATION*/

    TxMessage->IDE = CAN_ID_STD;

    TxMessage->DLC = 2;

    TxMessage->StdId = 0x321;

    TxMessage->RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
}

void Init_RxMes(CanRxMsg *RxMessage)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;

    RxMessage->StdId = 0;

    RxMessage->IDE = CAN_ID_STD;

    RxMessage->DLC = 0;

    RxMessage->FMI = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        RxMessage->Data[i] = 0;
    }
}

void CAN_setup(void)
{
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_CAN1, ENABLE); //Enable the clock for CAN

    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

    /* Configure CAN1 RX pin */

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    /* Configure CAN1 TX pin */

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource0, GPIO_AF_9);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource1, GPIO_AF_9);
    /* Enable the CAN global Interrupt */

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = CAN1_SCE_IRQn;

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;

    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = CAN1_RX1_IRQn;

    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    CAN_DeInit(CAN1);

    /* Configure CAN1 **************************************************/

    /* Struct init*/

    CAN_StructInit(&CAN_InitStructure);

    /* CAN cell init */
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_TTCM = DISABLE;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_ABOM = DISABLE;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_AWUM = DISABLE;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_NART = DISABLE;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_RFLM = DISABLE;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_TXFP = DISABLE;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Mode = CAN_Mode_Normal;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_SJW = CAN_SJW_1tq;

    /* CAN Baudrate = 125kbps (CAN clocked at 36 MHz) */
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS1 = CAN_BS1_9tq;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS2 = CAN_BS2_8tq;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Prescaler = 16;
    CAN_Init(CAN1, &CAN_InitStructure);

    /* CAN filter init */
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterNumber = 0;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMode = CAN_FilterMode_IdMask;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterScale = CAN_FilterScale_32bit;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;

    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterActivation = ENABLE;
    CAN_FilterInit(&CAN_FilterInitStructure);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    uint8_t TransmitMailbox = 0;

    CAN_setup(); // Set up CAN interface

    Init_TxMes(&TxMessage);
    init_pin(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_8, GPIO_Mode_OUT, GPIO_Speed_50MHz, GPIO_OType_PP, GPIO_PuPd_UP);

    while (1)
    {
        TxMessage.Data[0] = 0xAA;
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_8); // Transmit data

        TransmitMailbox = CAN_Transmit(CAN1, &TxMessage);

        i = 0;
        while ((CAN_TransmitStatus(CAN1, TransmitMailbox) != CANTXOK))
            ;                              // I put a breakpoint here to check
                                           // and found the message is pending.

        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_8); // Transmit data

        //i++;
    }
}
```

I think there is the problem, but how can I solve it?

Stacking in loop.

```
while ((CAN_TransmitStatus(CAN1, TransmitMailbox) != CANTXOK)
```

Comment: This looks like you forgot about the 120 Ohms resistors.

Comment: Where can  I put the 120 ohm res. I am using just STM32 and computer

Comment: Should I put between rx and tx pins ?

Comment: Yes. https://www.google.com/search?q=CAN+120Ohm You can put 60Ohm instead of two 120Ohm just for testing.

Comment: I've tried bu it didnt work. Again I am seeing just line.

Comment: I thnk stacking this line but why while ((CAN_TransmitStatus(CAN1, TransmitMailbox) != CANTXOK)

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386630/close-flag-disputed).

Comment: Are you sure you don't see anything on the oscilloscope? What if you set the oscilloscope to single shot (and the appropriate (positive or negative) edge triggering)? (The CAN controller may go into *bus off* mode very quickly if it doesn't have another CAN device to talk to).